# Can you place an instance of a member of a list within a regex to match in python?

Tags: python, regex, list, parsing, pattern-matching

So essentially I am trying to read lines from multiple files in a directory and using a regex to specifically find the beginnings of a sort of time stamp, I want to also place an instance of a list of months within the regex and then create a counter for each month based on how many times it appears. I have some code below, but it is still a work in progress. I know I closed off date_parse, but I that's why I'm asking. And please leave another suggestion if you can think of a more efficient method. thanks.

```
months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun',\
          'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','  Dec']
date_parse = re.compile('[Date:\s]+[[A-Za-z]{3},]+[[0-9]{1,2}\s]')
counter=0
for line in sys.stdin:
    if data_parse.match(line):
        for month in months in line:
            print '%s %d' % (month, counter)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a regular expression, you can have a list of alternative patterns, separated using vertical bars.

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

```
from collections import defaultdict

date_parse = re.compile(r'Date:\s+(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)')

c = defaultdict(int)

for line in sys.stdin:
    m = date_parse.match(line)
    if m is None:
        # pattern did not match
        # could handle error or log it here if desired
        continue # skip to handling next input line
    month = m.group(1)
    c[month] += 1
```

Some notes:

- I recommend you use a raw string (with `r''` or `r""`) for a pattern, so that backslashes will not become string escapes.  For example, inside a normal string, `\s` is not an escape and you will get a backslash followed by an 's', but `\n` is an escape and you will get a single character (a newline).
- In a regular expression, when you enclose a series of characters in square brackets, you get a "character class" that matches any of the characters.  So when you put `[Date:\s]+` you would match `Date:` but you would also match `taD:e` or any other combination of those characters.  It's perfectly okay to just put in a string that should match itself, like `Date:`.

Comment: Thanks steveha, never heard of defaultdict before. I think this could work.

Comment: ok. btw, how do you print a defaultdict object using formatting?

Comment: A `defaultdict` acts just like a plain old `dict` in every way, except that if you try to look something up and it isn't in there, it's automatically added.  If you want to print a list of months found, along with their counts, you could loop over your `defaultdict` the same as any other dict:  `for month in c: print("%s: %d" % (month, c[month])`  But that would print the months in random order.  I suggest you make a list of months like `lst_months = ['Jan', 'Feb', ..., 'Dec]` and then loop over the months in that list, and printing them or whatever.